# 配列を要素に持つタプルの要素ごとの和

Tags: python, numpy

numpy 配列を要素に持つ複数のタプルについて、要素ごとに配列の和を求めるコードを書きたいのですが誰か教えて頂けないでしょうか。例えば、

```py
tuple1 = (np.array([1,2], [3,4]), np.array([5,6],[7,8]))
tuple2 = (np.array([1,1], [1,1]), array([1,1],[1,1]))
```

があって、

```py
(array([[2,3],[4,5]]), array([[6,7],[8,9]]))
```

と出力させたいのですがうまい書き方はないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 何やら `tuple1` と `tuple2` の定義がおかしいですが…。 まぁ、出力結果から察するに `tuple(map(np.add, tuple1, tuple2))` としても良いかと。

Comment: 前の方のコメントを実行しました。なるほど。勉強になりました。
>>> tuple1 = (np.array([[1,2], [3,4]]), np.array([[5,6],[7,8]]))
>>> tuple2 = (np.array([[1,1], [1,1]]), np.array([[1,1],[1,1]]))
>>> tuple(map(np.add,tuple1,tuple2))
(array([[2, 3],
       [4, 5]]), array([[6, 7],
       [8, 9]]))
>>>

Comment: うまくいきました！ありがとうございます